# Convert string to decimal in Cube

Tags: ssas

I'm creating a cube and the person who wrote the software made a productSize field in the data a varchar(50) instead of a numeric data type.  It is also unusual in that it might, for instance, contain a 9 or a 4.5x2.  Can a calculated measure convert the varchar to a decimal in this situation?

Edit: Now I realize I can create a Named Calculation by right clicking the table column in the DSV.  I still need to figure out how to code the expression though.  This is all I have so far...

```
CASE
WHEN SUBSTRING(ProductSize, 2,1) = 'x' THEN 0 // detects an 'x' in char 2 but I need to detect an x anywhere, and verify the string can be converted to a number 
ELSE
    cast(ProductSize as DECIMAL)
END
```

Comment: This is now a question related to the SQL of your underlying relational database. Assuming SQL Server, the patindex() function may help you.
But without knowing what can or cannot appear in the string, it is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was a simple in that I just use SQL to create a Named Calculation in the DataSet view.  As stated above, it is just a matter of creating a parse statement using SQL syntax.  The following expression works for now.

```
CASE
WHEN ISNUMERIC(ProductSize)<>1 THEN 
    0 // zero for now, later figure out SQL to parse alpha data
ELSE
    cast(ProductSize as INT)
END
```